# Power shell script to export the Sharepoint site inactive for more than 90 days

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-powershell

I need help with PS script to fetch data of inactive sites for more than 90 days.

URL - https://mobileintra-admin.sharepoint.com/

Kindly help with the powershell script or any other method to fetch the data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below powershell script in order to get [inactive/unused sharepoint sites collections in past 30 days](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/sharepoint-online-find-unused-sites-using-powershell.html).

```sh
$TenantAdminURL = "https://Crescent-Admin.SharePoint.com"
$TenantURL = "https://Crescent.SharePoint.com"
$DaysInActive = 30 # number of days to check since last modified (Mention 90 to retrieve 90 days past list)
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\InactiveSites.csv"
 
#Connect to Admin Center
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TenantAdminURL -Credentials $Cred
     
#Get All Site collections - Exclude BOT, Video Portals and MySites
$SiteCollections = Get-PnPTenantSite -Filter "Url -like $TenantURL -and Url -notlike '-my.sharepoint.com/' -and Url -notlike '/portals/'"
 
#Calculate the Date
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysInActive).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
 
#Get All Site collections where the content modified
$InActiveSites = $SiteCollections | Where {$_.LastContentModifiedDate -le $Date} | Select Title, Url, LastContentModifiedDate, Template, StorageMaximumLevel
 
#Export to CSV
$InActiveSites
$InActiveSites | Export-Csv -Path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

For more information, you can refer [HERE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293001/how-to-identify-inactive-unused-sites-within-sharepoint-online).